# ADODB Command With Insert and Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, adodb

I am attempting to send a command using `ADODB.Command` in VBA. I know the connection and command work properly, as they are used in several places in the code. However, I am having trouble getting a dual insert/select to work. I keep getting a recordset with fields of count 0. I'm more familiar with using C# SqlCommand objects, which allow this sort of stacked commands. Is there a way to do this in VBA using ADODB? Code below:

NOTE: reader2 is an `ADODB.Recordset`. Connecting to Microsoft SQL Server using TSQL

```
        comm2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblTest (F1,F2,F3,F4,F5) VALUES(?,?,'Running',?,0); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()"
        comm2.Parameters.Append comm2.CreateParameter("@f1", adVarChar, adParamInput, Len(f1) + 1, f1)
        comm2.Parameters.Append comm2.CreateParameter("@f2", adVarChar, adParamInput, 1, f2)
        comm2.Parameters.Append comm2.CreateParameter("@f3", adDate, adParamInput, 0, Now)
        Set reader2 = comm2.Execute
        scopeId = reader2.Fields(0)
        reader2.Close
        comm2.Parameters.Delete (0)
        comm2.Parameters.Delete (0)
        comm2.Parameters.Delete (0)
```

Comment: @mehow reader2 is an ADODB.recordset. I've added above.

Comment: If you are hitting an Access database this won't work because Access doesn't support batch commands. Im fairly sure it doesn't support `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` either. You would need to use `@@IDENTITY`. Either way before you execute the command add `Comm2.CommandType = adCmdText`.  Then run the two commands seperatly on the same connection.  After the insert change the CommandText and run the identity select code.

Comment: @Fred I am connecting to a Microsoft SQL Server using TSQL, not Access. I've attempted to split the two commands, but "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()" returns NULL when run separate from the insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by using

```
Set reader2 = reader2.NextRecordset
```

after the command execution. The batched commands create a list of recordsets, the first of which is the recordset belonging to the insert, not the select.